# Neo4j : K-Hop at distance 3 with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, traversal

Is it possible to get, from a starting node, the nodes that are exactly at a distance 3 of it ?

I know that it's possible to achieve this result with the Neo4J Java APi and his traverser framework :

```
TraversalDescription td = graphDb.traversalDescription()
                            .breadthFirst()
                            .relationships( Neo4JBenchmark.RelTypes.Knows, Direction.OUTGOING )
                            .uniqueness( Uniqueness.NODE_GLOBAL )
                            .evaluator(Evaluators.excludeStartPosition())
                            .evaluator(Evaluators.fromDepth(3))
                            .evaluator(Evaluators.toDepth(3));
ResourceIterator<Node> traverser = td.traverse(startNode).nodes().iterator();
```

I was wondering if I can do the same with Cypher ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MATCH path = (a)-[:knows*3..3]->(c)
  WHERE id(a) = startNodeID
  WITH path, 
       shortestPath ( (a)-[:knows*..2]->(c) ) as sPath
    WHERE sPath IS NULL
    UNWIND nodes (path) as node
      WITH path, 
           collect (distinct node) as collect
        WHERE size (collect) = length (path) + 1
RETURN 
  DISTINCT collect [ length (path) ]
```

1. First we find all paths of length 3 from the starting node
2. Then count the number of unique nodes in each path
3. If the node number is one more than the length of the path, then the path is not self-intersecting, and return the last node in this path

**Upd**: Add check that there are no short path with less than the required length.

Comment: Hi, the result that is returned by this query is not the same as the one returned by the traverser the APi.

 It's a bit tricky, imagine the example : 1->2->3->4 and 1->4, node 4 is at distance 1 and not at distance 3 from node 1. However, your query will count it as at distance 3.

Comment: ok thanks, now it's alright but remove the "," after "spath" in your query ;)